# Byte array output as an Image

Tags: asp.net, image, arrays

I know it is be possible to do this:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/MyImageHandler.ashx?imageid=2" />
```

...but I have a case where the byte array data is only available to the Page (ie, not available in the session, and cannot be referenced by an id) so I can't point the ImageUrl to a different page.

Is there a way of giving an asp:Image the byte array to render as an Image?

Comment: Where is the byte array coming from?

Comment: I have update my answer.. check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only decent solution to this is to put the byte array in session.  If you're concerned about uniqueness (multiple people getting each other's byte arrays), use a random GUID as the key.

Comment: I'm going to have to give the green tick to this one, just because it would achieve the result, still not in the way I would want it to though - but I'm going to have to conceed that there is no answer to this one

Answer (score 2):

The major hurtle you're going to have to deal with is that an `<asp:Image/>` element gets rendered as a regular `<img />`, which needs a `src` attribute that points at a URL.

That being the case, I see two hairy alternatives:

- Use the technique described [here](http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html) to embed your image encoded in Base64 in the `src` attribute. Note that this does **not** work with Internet Explorer.
- Embed your Base64-encoded image into the page as a hidden `<input />` element. You could then use JavaScript to POST that data *back* to the server, which would just send it back to the browser using `Response.Write()` (being sure to set the Content-Type appropriately, of course).

Comment: Yes, I had considered the second option there but had to throw it away as it made me feel a little queasy throwing the data back and forth in that way.  Good idea though!

Comment: If you're thinking about the second option, you might as well use Session instead (like my answer).

Comment: Storing the image in the Session is clearly the better alternative (see also: a database). But if, for whatever reason, you don't have access to either of those (and the filesystem...) then this is really your only option.